# How to set the login credentials for Docker Desktop in Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

The login in my Docker Desktop on Ubuntu fails with the error message you can see in the picture [login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n39Ym.png). This happens in a similar way for every other docker command that is related to credentials such as "docker logout" which leads to:

*Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: could not erase credentials:
https://index.docker.io/v1/: error erasing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:` no usernames for [https://index.docker.io/v1/``](https://index.docker.io/v1/%60%60)*

or "docker login":
*Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:` no usernames for [https://index.docker.io/v1/``](https://index.docker.io/v1/%60%60)*

On the Docker Desktop app, I can click on cancel and then try "sign in" again manually which leads me to the browser and afterward to a successful login so I am sure that my credentials are correct and it has to be something with my config file.

I tried deleting the config.json in .docker and then login again but it does not work. I get an encrypted entry for "auth" so I assume the credentials are stored as they should be. I also gave read permissions to all files and directories in .docker but that also did not change anything.

The versions of my apps:

- Docker: 23.0.3
- Docker Desktop: 4.18.0
- Docker Engine: 20.10.24
- Ubuntu: 22.04.2

I would appreciate any suggestions or help. Thanks!